# Are bandwidth sharing apps such as peer2profit, IPRoyal and PacketStream risky?

Tags: wifi, proxy, smartphone, desktop

Apps like *peer2profit*, *IPRoyal* and *PacketStream* allow you to sell your unused internet bandwidth to others for passive income. Supposedly you could earn about 30 to 75 dollars a month from using these apps.

But are there any risks tied to running these apps on your smartphone or laptop? 
If so, what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is probably similar in the best case to opening a "public" portion of your WiFi (with good network segmentation) in a crowded area.  Traffic which some agencies (CIA, FBI, NSA, etc, etc) or copyright organizations could take issue with might be attributed to you.

In the worst case, the software is ill conceived or contains vulnerabilities which gives users unfettered access to your computer or network.

And frankly, the "per IP" portion of peer2profit might suggest the underlying intention of this is to build a pay to play botting network.  Not something I'd want to be involved with, three letter organizations non-withstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, its a very bad idea to give up control of the data pipes for your IP. It is not worth the small earnings you get for the issues you face due to a bad IP score.

These companies target residential IPs (residential broadband subscribers) so they can sell this service to accounts that want to use your IP address. Because of proxy and VPN abuse, many IPs originating from data centers are now blocked by default. People use your IP for web scraping (market research), to bypass limits on account creation for shoe/toy drops, concert tickets, game systems, etc. Multiple accounts can also be used to scale earnings (sign up bonus, coupons for free products, etc) and potentially damage company financials. These bandwidth companies say they vet customers and they don't allow illegal activities (internet fraud, virus distribution, DDoS attack, etc). Unfortunately, it is still theoretically possible a bad actor could use your IP for illegal purposes before the vendor shuts down the customer account. This is a worst case scenario.

After 1-3 months of use, your IP will be flagged as a known proxy. What this mean is that your IP address will have a low quality score. The impact for you is Google reCaptcha and HCaptcha will work harder to verify you're not a bot. CloudFlare web sites could also require a captcha or even outright deny entrance if you are a bad actor.

This is not worth it. You will not earn $30 to $75 a month. Only if you're good at affiliate marketing and know how to get signups under you, but you will most likely only make $2 to $5/mo. And that's only good for 3 months until the bandwidth company says your IP is bad and dump you.

I won't say these bandwidth companies are a scam because they do pay you, but the consequences of participation is not disclosed. I think most people would not do it if they really knew what the end result is.

I know this isn't an infosec response, but since you asked, I wanted to give you experience from someone whose run HoneyGain, Peer2Profit, PackStream, EarnApp, and PiggyBox.